# can't find zsh history on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, zsh, terminal.app

When I log into the Terminal app on OSX my default shell is `/bin/bash`.
Entering `echo $HISTFILE` points me to `/Users/monkeybrain/.bash_history` and `head $(echo $HISTFILE)` shows me that the file contains history entries.

If I then type `zsh` to switch shell a couple of weird things happen.
Firstly even though my prompt changes (so it looks like I'm in the new shell) my `$SHELL` environment variable still points to `/bin/bash`. The `$HISTFILE` variable is now empty, and there is no such file as `~/.zsh_history`. Also, I can't use `Ctrl-A` or `Ctrl-E` to move through the command line.

What's happening here?

Many thanks,

MB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The `SHELL` environment variable is usually not modified by the shell. It usually contains the full path to the current user's login shell, *not* the shell currently running. In most cases `SHELL` should be set before a shell starts. `zsh` does not change the value of `SHELL` and `bash` sets it back to the login shell if `SHELL` was unset.
- By default `HISTFILE` is unset in `zsh`. If you want to save the history, you have to set it to the file you want to use for that:

  ```
  HISTFILE="${HOME}/.zsh_history"
  ```

  You also need to set `SAVEHIST` to positive integer values to tell `zsh` how many lines to save in the `HISTFILE`, the default is `0` (Thanks [Monkeybrain](https://superuser.com/users/515918/monkeybrain) for the hint). You probably also want to raise `HISTSIZE`, which denotes how many lines of history are available in the shell session. Its default is only `30`. For example:

  ```
  HISTSIZE=2000
  SAVEHIST=2000
  ```

  This usually is done in the `~/.zshrc` configuration file.
- `zsh` tries to guess your key binding preferences by checking the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables. If either contains the string "vi" `zsh` will use the `viins` input mode. Neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> are by default bound in this mode. If you want to use the `emacs` input mode (the default in `bash`) you just need to run

  ```
  bindkey -e
  ```

  This can also be done in `~/.zshrc`

All in all it sounds like you are running `zsh` with the default configuration. If there is no `~/.zshrc` yet, you can just create it and add the necessary settings.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! I've learned lots here. I had no idea that Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E was 'emacs mode' - I just assumed it was standard shell behaviour. Also the textbook I have been using to learn about the shells has misled me regarding how zsh handles history files. Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed post.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else having this issue, I should add that in order for .zsh_history to be populated, as well as setting HISTFILE I needed to set SAVEHIST to a non-zero value.

Comment: @Monkeybrain Thanks for the hint. I added it to the answer.